# Not able to add a string to array from a variable in php:

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, xmlhttprequest

I am new to php. I have been trying to construct a array in php and encode it to JSON. This will be received using `xmlhttprequest` on the client side.

But there is a problem. I am not able to write a variable to the array.

This is what I am trying to do.

```
$name=$_GET['username'];
if ( strcmp( $name, 'harry' ) ) {
  $arr['status'] = 'success';
  $arr['name'] = $name;
  echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

But when I make a request on the client side. I get a null value in place of the variable. everything else in the array is fine except this value.

the response text that i get is

```
{"status":"success","username":null}
```

Am I doing something wrong in assigning the value?

Thank you

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you do an echo on $_GET['username'] to check if you are getting name from the request or not.

Comment: I tried  echo $_GET['username'] but it returns a blank string. But the string comparison if ( strcmp( $name, 'harry' ) ) evaluates to true. which means I am getting the string from the client right?

Thank you

Comment: use strcmp( $name, 'harry' )===0 as mentioned by itachi. But the problem is clear you are not getting anything in the request.

Comment: try using $arr['username'] instead of $arr['name']. I think the problem is that you're mixing the keys in the array. $arr['name'] creates a new element in the array that is different that $arr['username']

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'username' key in the array you're sending to the client side, you should use $arr['name'] instead

Comment: oh, sorry. yes, it shows "name":null.
How do i solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: how are you printing this array on the client side ? can you post the line of code that you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the benefit of using strcmp() in this scenario, however this will correct your problem

```
if ( strcmp( $name, 'harry' ) === 0) {
```

the usage of strcmp() is a bit counter intuitive here, so you could use

```
if ( $name === 'harry' ) {
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. I looks like there is no 'username' being passed at all so `strcmp(null, 'harry')` evaluates to true.

Comment: Strange, I get int(-5) from that function, either way the PHP manual states: _strcmp() Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal._ so an explicit test on int(0) is required for "true" outcome of both strings being the same

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me... Check it

```
$name=$_GET['username'];
if(strcmp($name,'harry')==0)
{
$arr['status']= 'success';
$arr['name']=$name;
echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name=$_GET['username'];
if ( strcmp( $name, 'harry' )===0 ) {
  $arr['status'] = 'success';
  $arr['username'] = $name; <---------- changed the index in $arr from 'name' to 'username'
  echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

`strcmp` returns 0 if two strings are equal (**remember it is case sensitive**)

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured out the problem. Yes, I had made a mistake in constructing the URL.

Thanks for all the help